# python, save data to file in loop

Tags: python, arrays

I would like to save arrays in loop to one file, so instead of,

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
y = np.array([7,6,5,2,1])
np.savetxt('out.txt', np.array([x,y]))
```

I would like to be able to add arrays in loop:

```
for i in range(0,2):
    x[i] = np.array([1,2,3,8,3])
    np.savetxt('out.txt', x[i])
```

and do not overwrite previous arrays. 
Is there anything else except savetxt I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save as plain text you can do:

```
with open('out.txt', 'a') as f:
    for i in range(0,2):
        x[i] = np.array([1,2,3,8,3])
        np.savetxt(f, x[i])
```

Note the 'a' for 'append'.

Answer (score 1):

`np.savez()` is made just for this: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html#numpy.savez

Not only will it let you save multiple arrays in one file, even if they have different columns etc., it will be more efficient and compact.